# How can i add a new template hook in my Cs-cart template?

Tags: cs-cart

My website using cs-cart 4.0, I need a template hook right above the body tag, how can I do this in cs-cart 4.0? (I want create a new hook for my own! How can I do it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that by adding
`{hook name="index:my_hook"}{/hook}`
into file `design/themes/basic/templates/index.tpl` but please take in consideration on a future update the hook may be removed and you will be needed to add it again